# Updating ListView after selecting Item from Dialog Window

Tags: android, listview, filter, dialog

I've got the following Problem.

I have a ListView which displays me Articles with different Categories.
When I select a Category from my Dialog Window and press the PositiveButton "OK", I want to update my ListView, that it now lists only the Articles from the Category, selected in the Dialog Window.

I created an interface in the DialogFragment, which is a callback to get value from the Dialog.

This is the Class:

```
public class SelectFilterDialog extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
private static int mSelectedIndex;
private static String mSelectedCategory;
private String[] categories = {"All", "Announcements","Commerce","Development", "Distributions", "Front","Kernel","Legal", "Letters", "Press", "Security"};
static OnDialogSelectListener mDialogSelectorCallback;


//callback method to get values from a Dialog
public interface OnDialogSelectListener{
    public void onSelectedOption();
}

public static SelectFilterDialog newInstance(int selected) {
    final SelectFilterDialog dialog = new SelectFilterDialog();
    mSelectedIndex = selected;
    return dialog;
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Select Filter");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(categories, mSelectedIndex, this);

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    switch (which){
        case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:{
            dialog.dismiss();
            mDialogSelectorCallback.onSelectedOption();
        }break;
        case Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:{
            dialog.cancel();
        }break;
        default:
            mSelectedIndex = which;
            setSelectedCategory(categories[which]);
            break;
    }
}

public void setDialogSelectListener(OnDialogSelectListener listener){
    this.mDialogSelectorCallback = listener;
}

public void setSelectedCategory(String category){
    this.mSelectedCategory = category;
}

public static String getSelectedCategory(){
    return mSelectedCategory;
}

public static int getSelectedIndex(){
    return mSelectedIndex;
}
```

}

In my SearchFragment Class , i show the List and implement the Interface from the SelectFilterDialog Fragment. 
In the Method, i update the selectedCategory, after pressing the OK button, and then update the adapter with notifyDataSetChanged()

SearchFragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_bar_filter: {
            showDialog();
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

void showDialog() {
    SelectFilterDialog dialog = SelectFilterDialog.newInstance(preSelectedValue);
    dialog.setDialogSelectListener(this);
    dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}

@Override
public void onSelectedOption() {
    selectedCategory = dialog.getSelectedCategory();
    preSelectedValue = dialog.getSelectedIndex();

    Log.i(TAG, "selectedCategory : " +selectedCategory);
    article_list_adapter.updateCategory(selectedCategory);
}
```

In my Adapter, i receive the Category in my updateCategory and fill the currentArticle List with the Articles with the correct Category.
This works fine.
After that i call NotifyDataSetChanged to update the view.

```
   public void updateCategory(String category) {
    this.currentArticles.clear();
    this.selectedCategory = category;
    for (Article article : entireArticles) {
        if (category.equals(article.getCategory())) {
            currentArticles.add(article);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But in the getView it throws an IndexOutOfBounce exception.
After selecting a Category from the dialog, e.g "Kernel", it adds only my 3 Kernel Categories to the currentArticle List, which is fine.
But int the getView statement:

```
Article currentArticle = currentArticles.get(_position);
```

It points on index 3 , though there are only 3 elements in the list.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
                                                                               at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                               at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                               at klinar.kronlachner.binder.app.Article_List_Adapter.getView(Article_List_Adapter.java:99)
```

Can you help me ? :)

```
public Article_List_Adapter(Context _c, int textViewResourceId, List<Article> articles) {
    super(_c, textViewResourceId, articles);
    this.entireArticles = new ArrayList<Article>();
    this.currentArticles = new ArrayList<Article>();
    entireArticles.addAll(articles);
    currentArticles.addAll(articles);
    this.storedArticles = new ArrayList<Article>(articles);
}

public View getView(int _position, View _convertView, ViewGroup _parent) {
    View view = _convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_list_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.article_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_category_icon);
        viewHolder.articleTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_title);
        viewHolder.articleCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_category);
        viewHolder.articleDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_date);
        viewHolder.articleAuthor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_author);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) _convertView.getTag();
    }


    //Find the article to work with
    Article currentArticle = currentArticles.get(_position);


    //fill the Article_View
    switch (currentArticle.getCategory()) {
        case "Kernel": {
            viewHolder.article_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_letter_k);
        }
        break;
        case "Security": {
            viewHolder.article_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_letter_s);
        }
        break;
        default: {
            viewHolder.article_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_letter_s);
        }
    }
    viewHolder.articleTitle.setText(currentArticle.getTitle());
    viewHolder.articleCategory.setText(currentArticle.getCategory());
    viewHolder.articleDate.setText(currentArticle.getDate());
    viewHolder.articleAuthor.setText(currentArticle.getAuthor());


    return view;
```

Comment: Use `String.equals` instead of `==` for comparing String values

Comment: adjusted that, but that doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: I think need to call `mSelectedIndex = which;
            setSelectedCategory(categories[which]);` in `case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:`

Comment: like `case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:{
            dialog.dismiss();mSelectedIndex = which; setSelectedCategory(categories[which]);
            mDialogSelectorCallback.onSelectedOption();
        }break;`

Comment: no that works, in the SearchFragment Class i made an Log output, and it shows me the Correct String

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your adapter class
create two List one for AllCategoryArticle and another for currentCategoryArticle.

```
class ArticleAdapter{
ArrayList<Model> currentArticle;
ArrayList<Model> entireArticle;
String selectedCategory="all";      //setting default category as "all"
public ArticleAdapter(ArrayList<Model> categoryList){
    this.entireList=categoryList;
    this.currentList=this.entireList;
}
//create updateCategory in adapter
/*call this method(updateCategory()) in you frgament/activity to update the adapter 
  according to you category that is selected in dialog
*/
public void updateCategory(String category){
    this.currentArticle.clear();
    this.selectedCategory=category;
    for(Model item: entireArticle){
        if(category.equals(item.getCategory()))
        {
            currentArticle.add(item);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
........
........
@Override
public View getView(int _position, View _convertView, ViewGroup _parent) {
View view = _convertView;
ViewHolder viewHolder;

if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_list_row, null);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.article_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_category_icon);
    viewHolder.articleTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_title);
    viewHolder.articleCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_category);
    viewHolder.articleDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_date);
    viewHolder.articleAuthor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_author);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) _convertView.getTag();
}

//Find the article to work with
Article currentArticle = articles.get(_position);
//just remove if condition because already you have filtered article by category in currentArticle
//fill the Article_View
switch (currentArticle.getCategory()) {
    case "Kernel": 
        viewHolder.article_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_letter_k);
        break;
    case "Security": 
        viewHolder.article_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_letter_s);
        break;
        default: 
            viewHolder.article_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_letter_s);

    }
    viewHolder.articleTitle.setText(currentArticle.getTitle());
    viewHolder.articleCategory.setText(currentArticle.getCategory());
    viewHolder.articleDate.setText(currentArticle.getDate());
    viewHolder.articleAuthor.setText(currentArticle.getAuthor());
  return view;
 }
}
```

Do this in your Activity/Fragment which has tha ArticleAdapter 
modification in onSelectedOption() method in your activity/Fragment

```
@Override
public void onSelectedOption() {
selectedCategory = dialog.getSelectedCategory();
preSelectedValue = dialog.getSelectedIndex();

Log.i(TAG, "selectedCategory : " +selectedCategory);
article_list_adapter.updateSelectedCategory(selectedCategory);
Log.i(TAG, "adapter Category : " +article_list_adapter.getSelectedCategory());

/*
    call updateCategory() instead of notifyDataSetChanged()
    updateCategory() will update your adapter
*/
//article_list_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
article_list_adapter.updateCategory(selectedCategory);
```

}

**Problem in your code is**
your trying to update the adapter using notifyDataSetChanged without updating your list.

notifyDataSetChanged() will work when there is an update in adapter model not in any variable in your adapter . see  this [how notifyDataSetChanged works in listView](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html)

**EDIT:changes in adapter class**

```
   class Adapter{
     ArrayList entireArticle;
     ArrayList currentArticle;

     public Adapter(Context context,ArrayList list){
       this.entireArticle=new ArrayList();
       this.currentArticle=new ArrayList();

       entireArticle.addAll(list);    
       currentArticle.addAll(list);
  }

  public void updateCategory(String category){
    this.currentArticle.clear();
    this.selectedCategory=category;
    if(category.equals("All")){ // add all article from entrieArticle if category=="all"
       this.currentArticle.addAll(entireArticle);
    }else{   //otherwise filter the article
         for(Model item: entireArticle){
           if(category.equals(item.getCategory()))
            {
             currentArticle.add(item);
            }
     }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
 ...............
 .................
}
```

do this changes in your adapter class and it will work i've checked this.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: It makes sense to me but now when it doesn't show me anything in the List :(

Comment: in the updateCategory, which you wrote, i changed the if statement to :
if (category.toUpperCase().equals(article.getCategory().toUpperCase())|| category.equals("All"))

to make sure that when All is selected, it displays everything againg. but it doesn't

Comment: now your using wrong condition. always "ONE" not equal to "one". so automatically you if statement will choose another condition i.e category.equals(all). that's why you are not getting selected category article. and also i wondering that why your checking category="all" in if statement.there is only one category will be send to adapter right then , it is redundant.

Comment: try like this if(article.getCategory.equals(category)), then log it under if condition, you will see the values, then investigate your code with this.If your facing any issue means please update your question with updated code block. so that it will be easy to help you on that.

Comment: the currentArticle List is filled right with my condition.
but i get IndexOutOfBounce exception as i described above :(

in getView i am running through CurrentArtice List now, which is the one which gets filled after calling the update method

Comment: I am checking to category = "All", so that when i select All in my dialog window, it shows me every Article again, because articles themeselves can't contain "All" as a value.

Comment: i edited my code , can you please take a look again ? :)

Comment: hey, see my edit this will give complete solution, If you still facing any issue means let me know